# How to correct Error with pointer to char struct in C?

Tags: c, pointers

i've been doing this code and i am new on using pointers.
It gives me the error

> assignment to 'char *' from incompatible pointer type 'char (*)[10]

and i don't know what can i do to correct it.

The code is as follows:

```
typedef struct dados_jogo
{
  float jogo; 
  char data[10]; 
  char equipa1[10]; 
  char equipa2[10]; 
  char jog1[50];
  char jog2[50];
  int mapas1; 
  int mapas2; 
  char *venc; 
} jogo;

typedef struct equipa
{
  char nome[10]; 
  jogador jogadores[NUM];
} team;
```

Main declarations:

```
char winner[10];
int op = 1;
int nj = 0, ng = 0;
char nomeficheiro[20];
char ficheiro[20];
jogador players[NUM];
jogo games[JOG];
team eq[EQP];
FILE *fp;
```

Piece of function where the error is:

```
if (games[0].mapas1 > games[0].mapas2)
{
  games[0].venc = &games[0].equipa1;
  strcpy(games[4].equipa1, games[0].venc);
  char *ptrw = &games[0].equipa1;
  for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
  {
    for (j = 0; j < 10; j++)
    {
      if (strcmp(games[i].jog1, eq[0].jogadores[j].nome) == 0)
      {
        eq[0].jogadores[j].rating = eq[0].jogadores[j].rating + 0.3;
      }
      if (strcmp(games[i].jog1, eq[1].jogadores[j].nome) == 0)
      {
        eq[1].jogadores[j].rating = eq[1].jogadores[j].rating - 0.2;
      }
    }
  }

}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which line does the error refer to?

Comment: The compiler prints a line number with the error message (and likely a column number too) or the IDE you are using shows you which line of code causes the error. When asking questions about compiler messages, always include that information in your post.

Comment: line "games[0].venc = &games[0].equipa1;"

Comment: i did, the error is on the top of the question.

Comment: @DuochannelYT: The error message is there, but the **line number** is not. (Of course, since you only provided some of the lines, we would not have the line number. In the future, you should provide a [mre] and/or indicate which line causes the error.)

Comment: got ir, noted, ty.

Answer (score 1):

In `char *ptrw = &games[0].equipa1;`, `games[0].equipa1` is an array of 10 `char`, so `&games[0].equipa1` is a pointer to an array of 10 `char`, which is a different thing from a pointer to a `char`. Likely you want `char *ptrw = games[0].equipa1;`.

Similarly, `games[0].venc = &games[0].equipa1;` should be `games[0].venc = games[0].equipa1;`.

Comment: You missed a `&`. The expression `&games[0].equipa1` is a pointer to an array of 10 `char`. The expression `games[0].equipa1` would (in most contexts) return a pointer to the first `char` in the  array `games[0].equipa1`

Comment: @HAL9000: Thanks, fixed.

Comment: So i took out most of the "&" but i still have some errors in other lines.

Comment: there is a line where i have this "ptrw = games[0].equipa1;".
How would i do it to have the pointer "ptrw" to point to the value of "games[0].equipa1"?